# Is it possible to change the width of an imshow matplotlib visualization?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a figure using `imshow` in `matplotlib` for which I can usefully set the width and height. I thought I could use `figsize` to do that, but it's performing the way I thought it would.

For example, using the following MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 100
width = 20
height = 20
Z = np.random.random((width,height))

G = np.zeros((width,height,3))

# Here we set the RGB for each pixel
G[Z>0.5] = [1,1,1]
G[Z<0.5] = [0,0,0]

plt.figure(figsize = (2, 5))
plt.imshow(G,interpolation='nearest')
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

If I change `figsize = (2, 5)` to `figsize = (2, 2)`, for example, the proportions don't change!

After trying a few different values I think this is because the graph is being rendered as a box instead of as a rectangle: no matter what I set `figsize` to the individual matrix entries are a constant box.

Is there a command that I can use to e.g. tell matplotlib to expand out to e.g. `800x400px`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default behavior of `imshow` is to set the aspect ratio of the host axes to be 'equal' (that is squares in data-units are squares in screen space).  If you do not care about this, just set the aspect to 'auto'.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


N = 100
width = 20
height = 20
Z = np.random.random((width, height))

G = np.zeros((width, height, 3))

# Here we set the RGB for each pixel
G[Z > 0.5] = [1, 1, 1]
G[Z < 0.5] = [0, 0, 0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 5))
ax.imshow(G, interpolation='nearest')
ax.set_aspect('auto')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ask a simple question, get an awesome answer from a team dev---thanks, and thanks for your work!